# Update url parameters on form submit based on selections

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to update the url with the selected options in the form and send it to session but i keep receiving : (Undefined variable: country).

How can fix this please ? and i am very beginner so excuse my dumb mistakes .

**My route :**

```
Route::post('/{country}/{region}/{city}', [

'as' => 'locationFinder',
'uses' => 'User\UserLocationsController@store']);
```

**My controller :**

```
class UserLocationsController extends Controller
{
public function store(Request $request, Country $country, Region $region, City $city)

{

    session()->put($country->name, $region->name, $city->name);

    return redirect()->route('welcome.index', [$country, $region, 
 $city]);

   }

 }
```

**My view :**

```
<form action="{{ route('locationFinder',[$country, $region, $city]) }}" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="country_id" id="country_id">
          <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">  Select Country </option>
            @foreach ($countries as $key => $value)
              <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="region_id" id="region_id">
          <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true"> Select Region </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="districts" id="districts">
          <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true"> Select City </option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

**My CountryController :**

```
  class CountryController extends Controller

{

public function countries(){
  $countries = Country::all();
  return view('welcome', compact('countries'));
}

public function regions(){
  $countries_id = Input::get('country_id');
  $regencies = Region::where('country_id', '=', $countries_id)->get();
  return response()->json($regencies);
}

public function cities(){
  $regions_id = Input::get('region_id');
  $districts = City::where('region_id', '=', $regions_id)->get();
  return response()->json($districts);
}


 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are you passing `country` to that view?

Comment: Hello , I am passing data from Country , Region , City models in a dynamic drop down select to the view

Answer (score 1):

in the controller you pass "$country"... but in your view you are using "$countries" in the foreach

**controller**:

```
..
return redirect()->route('welcome.index', [$country, $region, 
$city]);
..
```

**view**:

```
@foreach ($countries as $key => $value)
   <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hello ,  I am passing data from Country , Region , City models in a dynamic drop down select to the view , let me modify and add the other controller that's passed to the view